# Laravel display integer value into string in modal-view.blade

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Hello i had a modal which contain an data from my order, but there was some specific value that i would like to replace, like for example value of `group_id`. In my `view-modal.blade.php` the value of `group_id` is `int` and i would like to display it in my modal as a `String`, for example like :

```
if($group->group_id == 1){
    <input value="(2)ADAM GROUP">
}elseif($group->group_id == 2){
    <input value="(3)BRIAN GROUP">
}
```

and here is the JQuery that used to catch the order `id` in my `index.blade.php` and to display it in my `view-modal.blade` :

```
$('body').on('click', '.viewMediaOrder', function(){
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $.get('media-order/'+id+'/edit', function (data){
                    $('#modalHeading').html("View Media Order");
                    $('#viewMediaOrderSubmitButton').val("view-media-order");
                    $('#viewMediaOrderSubmitButton').prop('disabled',false);
                    $('#viewMediaOrderModal').modal('show');
                    $('#viewMediaOrderModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#id_view').val(data.id);
                    $('#nomor_view').val(data.nomor);
                    $('#nomor_reference_view').val(data.nomor_reference);
                    $('#periode_start_view').val(data.periode_start);
                    $('#periode_end_view').val(data.periode_end);
                    $('#category_id_view').val(data.category_id);
                    $('#type_id_view').val(data.type_id);
                    $('#agency_code_view').val(data.agency_code);
                    $('#agency_name_view').val(data.agency_name);
                    $('#advertiser_name_view').val(data.advertiser_name);
                    $('#advertiser_code_view').val(data.advertiser_code);
                    $('#brand_code_view').val(data.brand_code);
                    $('#brand_name_view').val(data.brand_name);
                    $('#version_code_view').val(data.version_code);
                    $('#nett_budget_view').val(data.nett_budget);
                    $('#gross_value_view').val(data.gross_value);
                    $('#nett_cashback_view').val(data.nett_cashback);
                    $('#nett_bundling_view').val(data.nett_bundling);
                    $('#spot_view').val(data.spot);
                    $('#accountexecutive_name_view').val(data.accountexecutive_name);
                    $('#group_id_view').val(data.group_id);
                    $('#userto_name_view').val(data.userto_name);
                    $('#notes_view').val(data.notes);
                    $('#attachment_name_view').val(data.attachment_name);
                })
        });
```

and here is the `group_id` input value in my `view-modal.blade.php` :

```
<div class="row mg-t-20">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Group Sales:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
                                <input name="group_id" id="group_id_view" class="form-control select2" readonly></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

so is anyone has an alternative way to display it? i have tried using `if` and `switch` but i don't know how to catch the `group_id` value, apologize for my english, thank you!.

EDIT :

here is my `controller.php`, `index` :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if(auth()->user()->is_admin){
                $data = MediaOrder::get();
            }elseif(auth()->user()->group_id){
                $data = MediaOrder::memberOf(auth()->user()->group_id)->get();
            }else{
                $data = MediaOrder::get();
            }
            return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('action',function($row){
                        $btn = '<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="View" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm button1 viewMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-eye mr-1"></i>View</a>';
                        if($row->isdisabled == 0 && !auth()->user()->is_traffic){
                            $btn = $btn.'<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="editMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm button1 editMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil mr-1"></i>Edit</a>

                            <a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" id="disableMediaOrder"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm button1 disableMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-power-off mr-1"></i>Disable</a>';
                        }
                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->editColumn('isdisabled', function($row){
                        
                        if($row->isdisabled == 0 && auth()->user()->is_traffic){
                            $combo = '<input data-id="'.$row->id.'" type="checkbox" class="checkedTraffic">';

                            return $combo;
                        }elseif($row->isdisabled == 0){
                            $row = "Active";

                            return $row;
                        }elseif($row->isdisabled == 1){
                            $row = "Disabled";

                            return $row;
                        }elseif($row->isdisabled == 2){
                            $row = "Checked by Traffic";

                            return $row;
                        }elseif(!auth()->user()->is_traffic){
                            $row = $row->isdisabled;

                            return $row;
                        }    

                            
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action','isdisabled'])
                    ->make(true);
        } else {

            \Meta::set('title', 'Media Order');
            $groups = Group::all();
            $media_order = DB::table('media_order')->get();
            $moo = MediaOrder::get();
            $selected = auth()->user()->group_id;
            $mediaOrder = MediaOrder::all();
            $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

            return view('media-order.index')->with(compact('users','moo','groups','selected','mediaOrder'));
        }
    }
```

And here is the `edit` view function :

```
public function edit($id)
    {       
        $where = array('id' => $id);
        $moe = MediaOrder::where($where)->first();
        return Response::json($moe);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your blade:

```
@if ($group->group_id == 1)
    <input value="(2)ADAM GROUP">
@elseif ($group->group_id == 2)
    <input value="(3)BRIAN GROUP">
@endif
```

Comment: sadly it didn't working, the `group_id` was there and show up in `console.log()` but it wont show up

Comment: Have you identified input type? Like this `<input type="text" value="(2)ADAM GROUP">`

Comment: yes, it still didn't working, it skip the `@if` value and just show the default one

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your `controller` code before displaying the `view-modal.blade.php`?

Comment: i already update my question